# Is the state $|0101\ldots\rangle+|1010\ldots\rangle$ an $N$-particle GHZ state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

We know GHZ state can write as:

$$ |\textrm{GHZ}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} |i\rangle \otimes \ldots \otimes |i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} (|\textrm{0}\rangle \otimes \ldots \otimes |\textrm{0}\rangle + \ldots + |d-1\rangle \otimes \ldots \otimes |d-1\rangle). $$

But in this [paper](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aax9743), the GHZ state ($d=2$) is write as:

$$ |\textrm{GHZ}_\textrm{N}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |0101\ldots\rangle + |1010\ldots\rangle ).$$

I wonder how to get the latter form of GHZ state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a GHZ state, but you can get it from a $d=2$ GHZ state by flipping every other qubit, so it is equivalent to a GHZ state up to local unitaries, and thus has the same entanglement properties as the GHZ state.

Comment: I understand. Thank you！